# What is the single name for this switch thing?

Tags: image-identification

I found this switch in South India. It is not moving and also I don't know
how to use it.

[image]

(*click on image to enlarge it*)

What is the single name for this switch thing ?

Comment: Did you know that there's a [home improvement SE site](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)? [Identification questions](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1162) seem to be on topic there, so it might be best to delete this question and ask there instead because I think the answer will probably involve domain-specific knowledge. (But that's just my thoughts...)

Comment: It says "million" in the bottom right corner.  There's a company called "Million electronics" based in Chennai.  (Googling "million electronics" gave it as the first hit.)  If it doesn't do anything, perhaps it's an old switch or wall outlet that was capped for safety and left vestigial on the wall.

Comment: The symbol looks like a fuse symbol.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Answer (score 1):

It is a fuse, not a switch. The symbol is the electrical symbol for a fuse.

One can google using the search words  "[indian fuse house](https://www.google.com/search?q=indian%20fuse%20house&source=lnms&tbm=isch)" and get a lot of images of fuses.

Compare the ones in this image to the image in the question.

[image: fuses]